# Dynamic ComboBox Datasource Form Load

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I'm creating a dynamic combo box and adding to a form.  I'm trying to fill the combo box with a DataSource from an ArrayList and then selecting an item in the combo box based off a value from a property.

Problem is, the combo box items don't get bound until after the Form_Load event has finished and the form is visible.  So the combo box is empty when I try to set the selected index of the combo box.  See code for what I'm doing in detail, and refer to comments in code:

```
Dim cboValues As New ComboBox
cboValues.Width = fieldControlWidth
cboValues.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

cboValues.Name = "cboResult"

For Each d As SystemTaskResult In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(SystemTaskResult))
    Dim cv As New ComboBoxDisplayValue(d.ToString, d)
    arrValues.Add(cv)
Next

cboValues.DataSource = arrValues
cboValues.DisplayMember = "Display"
cboValues.ValueMember = "Value"

Dim val As SystemTaskResult = DirectCast(p.GetValue(Me.Task, Nothing), SystemTaskResult)

'Was trying to get this to work, but commented out to try the below
'cboValues.SelectedIndex = cboValues.Items.IndexOf(New ComboBoxDisplayValue(val.ToString, val))

'Then this doesn't work because the combo box hasn't updated it's DataSource yet, which is probably the reason for the above not working as well.
For i = 0 To cboValues.Items.Count - 1
    cboValues.SelectedIndex = i
    If cboValues.SelectedValue = val Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

holdPanel.Controls.Add(cboValues)
```

How to select the right selected index for combo box without a hack (Load timer or something stupid like that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx). See :

[How do I execute code AFTER a form has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218732/how-do-i-execute-code-after-a-form-has-loaded)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the combo box items are still 0 in the Form.Shown event.  Remember this is a dynamic control, not a control already on the form.  Which I think is the issue here.

Comment: @ScottN Not sure why you insist on doing them in the same function, but you can try creating the ComboBox on the Shown event as well

Comment: Sorry, if I do my control creation in the Form Load, and then in the Form Shown try to set the combo box to the correct selected index the items are now populated, I was hoping to do this in the same function.  I guess not possible.

Comment: I know this is old question but I had same problem and I solved it by looping through List and then add each item by using Combobox1.Items.Add