# How to run code when form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms

I thought the Load event might help, but the following code just shows “Done” immediately.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
}

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Text = "Done";
}
```

How do I make it Sleep after the form is shown?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a Shown event for a windows form. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

Or if you are lazy, here you go:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += Form1_Shown;
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Text = "Done";
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **do not block** a form, process something and after show in its title "Done", cause that what you want to do, I presume. This gives to the user **blocked UI feeling**, which is not good.

It's definitely better to show some temporary "Wait for..." form and on completion of the operation/calculation you perform, show your main form.

Much more UX focused design.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) in the Form1_Load method and link its Elapsed event to a method that displays the message.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep(3000); in the Load event handler delays the form opening for 3 seconds. This why it does not work as you expect. A timer is the best solution.