# How do I pass the variable lines from Form1 to the UserControl.cs code?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in form1 including the Load event:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string readableRss;
        private List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            const int maxLines = 5;

            lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                               .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                               .ToList();
            newsFeed1.GetLines = lines;
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines
                         .Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Count() - maxLines))
                         .Take(maxLines)
                         .ToArray());
            /*const int maxLines = 5;

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, readableRss.Length - maxLines)).Take(maxLines).ToArray());*/

                this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
                SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue });
                //set this Variable to the Height of the Control to display one label at a time
                this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
                this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
                this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
        }
```

When im using a breakpoint on :

```
newsFeed1.GetLines = lines;
```

I see that GetLines is not null and got the content from lines.

The problem is in the NewsFeed.cs UserControl:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class NewsFeed : UserControl
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker;
        public List<string> GetLines = new List<string>();
```

Here GetLines is null ! 
I want that GetLines will be contain what is in the variable lines in form1.
In Form1 lines contain 100 indexs. When i assign in Form1 the GetLines to lines i see that GetLines also contain 100 indexs.

But when im using breakpoint on the NewsFeed code on the line:

```
public List<string> GetLines = new List<string>();
```

GetLines contain 0 indexs its empty.

I want to pass the content of the variable lines from form1 to the variable GetLines in Newsfeed.cs

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `newsFeed1` object?

Comment: Firstly, GetLines is a property, not a variable, and that's a terrible name for a property because it implies a method.  It's also rarely a good idea to have a collection property with a setter.  They should pretty much always be read-only.  Anyway, what you should be doing is placing a watch on 'newsFeed1.GetLines' and checking it's value at the closing brace of the Load event handler.  You will find that it is not null.

Comment: It would be better if you will show us the part of code that is using Form1_Load and tell us exactly at which point you have null in GetLines.

Comment: Updated my question added the Load event of form1 and the beginning code of the UserControl. I want to pass the content in the variable lines in Form1 to the variable GetLines in the UserControl NewsFeed.

Comment: Andrei V in the designer since NewsFeed is a UserControl once i dragged it in form1 designer the variable newsFeed1 was  instantiating automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the condition that the usercontrol is loaded into that form, you can use the solution in this Question [How do I execute code AFTER a form has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218732/how-do-i-execute-code-after-a-form-has-loaded). Use the `Shown` event of the form.