# Are Generated Events Handled Immediately or After Code Execution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, event-handling

In my code I have a change event and another part of my code subscribes to this event.

The question is when my change event is raised, does execution of method that triggered the event halt and the event handler executes, or is the event queue'd with the OS and handled at the next opportunity, which will most likely be after the initial method completes?

Also, will this behavior change if the subscriber is in a different thread?

While debugging and stepping to the code, the code immediately goes to the event handler, just like with a method call which is not what I expected?

Here is an example to clarify what I am asking:

```
    Event Handler 1
    {
        {
            //Code Section 1
        }
        //*Trigger My Event Here
        {
           //Code Section 2
        }
    }

    Event Handler 2
    {
    }
```

I added that the code itself is actually an Event handler for an event triggered in another thread.

This thread can create many events simultaneously and adds them to a queue. When I trigger my own event in the middle of the event handler, will my Event Handler 2 execute right away or will all other instances of Event Handler 1 finish first?

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you show us the specific code you are referring to.

Comment: I added an example of how my code looks. I would like to know if the Event Handler should execute before Code Section 2. Also, if the event has been subscribed to by say 100 objects, will all event instances be handled before Code Section 2 runs?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events that are generated in response to a user action on the surface of the User Interface are placed in the Message Queue of the User Interface.

The message pump that operates on the UI thread executes these messages in the order they were received. If the UI is unresponsive because another event is already being serviced on the UI thread, new events will be dropped into the message queue until the message pump can get to them.

If you raise an event from the UI thread in your code, it *does not* get placed into the message queue.  It's equivalent to a method call; it gets executed immediately.

If you raise an event on the UI thread *from another thread* using `Invoke()` or `Control.Invoke()`, it gets [put into the Message Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218740/102937), waiting its turn.  `System.Winforms.Timer` will also do this.  Note that `Control.BeginInvoke` will *always* push the event onto the message queue, even if you called it from the UI thread, whereas `Control.Invoke` will execute immediately if you call it from the UI thread (in order to avoid a deadlock).

Comment: Will this change if I am also handling events from another external thread? That external thread can queue up several events. Will own event take priority and be handled first or will all events be handled in the order they were created?

Comment: See my fourth paragraph.

Comment: I see, the external events will go into a queue while my local events will be handled immediately unless I use BeginInvoke to queue them. That is exactly what I wanted to know.