# WIndows Forms Threading - Wait for Forms to Complete Rendering

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I know there are multiple Windows Forms threading questions out there.  I've browsed many of them but cannot seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a main form.  From this form code is executed to create a bunch of new forms which will be used to take image snapshots from which will then be added to a pdf document.

My problem at this stage is the new forms are not given enough time to complete rendering before the pdf document is created.  Thus I need to execute the forms on a different thread, wait for them to finish rendering (on top of that wait a few seconds longer), and then continue to generate the PDF document.

It's a lot of code so I'm going to try and explain what I'm trying to do with new  (reduced) code.

```
    public static void CreatePDFDocument()
    {
        List<Form> formsList = CreateForms(collectionIDs);
        CreatePDF(formsList);
    }


    public static List<Form> CreateForms(List<string> collectionIDs)
    {
        List<Form> formsList = new List<Form>();
        foreach (string id in collectionIDs)
        {
            Form chartForm;
            chartForm = new Form();
            chartForm.TopMost = false;
            chartForm.Height = 1024;
            chartForm.Width = 1400;
            chartForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            chartForm.AutoScroll = true;

            //CODE TO ADD CHART CONTROLS TO FORM
            //...
            //...
            //...
            formsList.Add(chartForm);
        }

        return (formsList);
    }

    public static void CreatePDF(List<Form> formsList)
    {
        foreach (var form in formsList)
        {
            foreach (var control in form.Controls)
            {
                //CODE TO CREATE BITMAP AND ADD IT TO PDF DOCUMENT
                //ACCESSING THE CONTROL HERE NEED TO BE  THREAD SAFE
            }
        }
    }
```

The code as seen above generates the PDF document before the rendering is completed.  Thus I get black images in the PDF document.  I need to run them on a separate thread, wait until everything is done and then move on to create the new PDF document (while accessing the forms in a thread safe manner).

I've tried many different threading code but the forms are either stuck in a thread when using the ShowDialog() function on the form itself or the forms close when they are done, and then I cannot access them anymore.

To access the forms in a thread safe manner, I'm using an extension method:

```
 public static void SynchronizedInvoke(this ISynchronizeInvoke sync,  Action action)
{
    // If the invoke is not required, then invoke here and get out.
    if (!sync.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Execute action.
        action();

        // Get out.
        return;
    }

    // Marshal to the required context.
    sync.Invoke(action, new object[] { });
}
```

Here is how I am generating the bitmaps with the extensions method:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(newPBWidth, newPBHeight);
form.SynchronizedInvoke(() => form.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), image.Size)));
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218732/how-do-i-execute-code-after-a-form-has-loaded. Use the given Event `Shown` to wait for the form to be finished

Comment: Does this event fire when all control on the form are done rendering as well?

Comment: `Shown` is called when the form is first shown ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) So the rendering is/should be done then. Minimizing and re-opening don't raise this event as a side note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked like a bomb.  Constructed it from my experience and advice given by Nico

```
public static List<Thread> formsThreadList = new List<Thread>();
public static List<string> formsFinishedLoading = new List<string>();
public static List<Form> formsList = new List<Form>();

public static void CreatePDFDocument()
{
    formsList = CreateForms(collectionIDs);

    Thread thread = new Thread(CreatePDFThreadFunction)
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}


 public static void CreatePDFThreadFunction()
 {
     while (formsFinishedLoading.Count() != formsThreadList.Count()) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
     CreatePDF(formsList, collectionList, path, "");
 }  


 public static void form_shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form frm = (Form)sender;
     frm.Refresh();
     formsFinishedLoading.Add(frm.Name);
 }



public static List<Form> CreateForms(List<string> collectionIDs)
{
    List<Form> formsList = new List<Form>();
    foreach (string id in collectionIDs)
    {
        Form chartForm;
        chartForm = new Form();
        chartForm.TopMost = false;
        chartForm.Height = 1024;
        chartForm.Width = 1400;
        chartForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        chartForm.AutoScroll = true;
        chartForm.Shown += new EventHandler(form_shown);

        //CODE TO ADD CHART CONTROLS TO FORM
        //...
        //...
        //...
        formsList.Add(chartForm);
    }

    return (formsList);
}

public static void CreatePDF(List<Form> formsList)
{
    foreach (var form in formsList)
    {
        foreach (var control in form.Controls)
        {
            //CODE TO CREATE BITMAP AND ADD IT TO PDF DOCUMENT
            //ACCESSING THE CONTROL HERE NEED TO BE  THREAD SAFE
        }
    }
}
```