# executing a function after a form has fully loaded

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function I want to run after a windows form has loaded. the function prints a "lol" forever. but right now it interupts the form initializing, but if i dont put it in the Form1 constructor then then function never gets called and never runs. is there no way to call this function after the form is open?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            do_stuff_forever();
        }
        public void do_stuff_forever() {
            while (1 < 2) { Debug.WriteLine(" lol "); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Form has Load event. You might want to call the method in the handler of load event of the form.

Comment: It should help you a bit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218732/how-do-i-execute-code-after-a-form-has-loaded

Comment: Just use a Timer and start it in the OnShown override.

Comment: Call it on the form load event and start on a new thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shown() event of the form to make it run AFTER the form has completely shown...but the innfinite loop will still monopolize the UI thread.  Put that ugly code on a different thread to make it work:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Shown += (s, e) =>
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (1 < 2) {
                Debug.WriteLine(" lol ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // optional?
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Form_Load event and open a new thread so UI will not stuck.